# How do I fix my bullet code so that when I shoot a second bullet from different direction, that doesn't change the first bullet's directions?

Tags: python, pygame

I'm having an issue where when I shoot one bullet in a certain direction, then I fire a second bullet in a different direction, the previous bullet changes direction too.

```
if bullet.x < 1919 and bullet.x > 0 and facing==-1 or bullet.x < 1919 and bullet.x > 0 and facing==1 :#boundry for bullets made small change
    bullet.x += bullet.vel
elif bullet.y < 803 and bullet.y> 0 and facing==2:#boundry for bullets made small change needs added to  main stage
    bullet.y -= bullet.vel    
elif bullet.y < 803 and bullet.y > 0 and facing==-2 :#needs added to main stage
    bullet.y -= bullet.vel 
else:
    bullets.pop(bullets.index(bullet))

keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
movemana=25#the cost when using that move need ot make function for  that later

if keys[pygame.K_SPACE] and mana>movemana and shootloop==0:
    #print(mana)
    mana-=movemana
    #print(mana)
    if man.up==True:
        facing=2
    if man.left==True:
        facing = -1
    if man.right==True:
        facing = 1
    if man.down==True:
        facing=-2
    print(facing)
    if len(bullets) < 5:
        bullets.append(projectile(round(man.x + man.width //2), round(man.y + man.height//2), 6, (0,0,0), facing))
    shootloop=1#cooldownrate
```

Comment: Don't do `if x == True` just do `if x`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like only part of your code is present, but I'll do my best with what's available.

It appears all your bullets are sharing the same global `facing` variable. `facing` gets set in the bottom portion of your code. Then, I presume, the top portion is called on each bullet, which means all of them will use the same `facing` value (whatever it was set to when the last bullet was created).

However, it looks like you're also storing that `facing` variable inside each bullet that gets created; see the line near the bottom that starts with `bullets.append(projectile(...` That value just isn't being used currently. So when checking the location of the bullet in the top half, try using `bullet.facing` (or whatever the name of that member is) instead of just `facing`.